# Meaning of Eclipse Icon Adornment

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse's Package Explorer View, objects can have an adornment which consists of an orange rectangle (or cylinder), like so:

[image]

I can't find it in the [icon reference](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) for Eclipse Indigo.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means the file is under version control. (i.e. cvs, svn, git or something else)

You can have a look for the meaning here : http://www.rorycullen.com/blog/2009/07/guide-to-subclipse-decorator-icons/

maybe not your version control system, but it's pretty standard in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer and useful reference link.

Comment: Not forgotten:) I just had to wait 5 minutes before the system allowed me to accept it.

Comment: Ha, sorry, I didn't know that!